# Building create-react-app fails on Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I'm using the [Mars buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack), and every time I try to build my site I get an error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Main.css' in
>   '/tmp/build_546fe78ab9ffb9c7a949b22c43e1d251/src'

I've tried moving the files around, linking them in different ways, and nothing seems to work. I followed Facebook's own instructions for enabling SASS, and I'm using their build scripts—which work fine locally on OSX.

My main file looks like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import './Main.css'

// Views
// Views here

// Components
import Navigation from './components/Navigation'
import Footer from './components/Footer'

class Main extends Component {
 render() {
  return(
   <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="primary-layout">
     <Navigation/>
     <Switch>
      // Routes in here
     </Switch>
     <div><Footer/></div>
    </div>
   </BrowserRouter>
  );
 }
}

export default Main;
```

The CSS file in question is in `/src/Main.css`.

The pertinent build script looks like this:

```js
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: do you get the same error when running `npm run build` or `yarn build` locally?

Comment: No, my local builds work fine and I can use nginx to run them without issue. I suspect this is some path/casing thing to do with moving from OSX to Linux on Heroku but I've no idea.

Comment: I mean you might be right. Have you tried simply renaming Main.css to main.css ? And change the import as well of course.

Comment: I actually did, yeah, It used to be `main.css` and I changed it. I also moved it from it's original path, which was at `./src/styles`, to no avail.